# Getting data from database and splitting it into multiple files using shell scripts

Tags: sql, linux, database, unix, export-to-csv

I have a requirement where i need to take data from data base through shell scripting. The data should be in the form of csv’s. Suppose i have 1M records in my table when i execute the shell script it should get split into multiple csv’s like 1lakh records per csv and 10 files(data-1.csv, data-2.csv, data-3.csv so on)

Comment: What database? Most of them have built-in methods to create CSV files from queries. E.g. MySQL has an option `INTO OUTFILE` in the `SELECT` query.

Comment: And the commands for running SQL queries from a shell script depend on the database.